# How do I style this mat-sidenav?

Tags: html, angular-material

I'm trying to get this side nav to below the logo. Like this example: [I'd love for it to look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p87pW.png)

Currently, I have this - where it shows 80% of it, but I believe I'm doing this wrong. [Here is what it looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilHkF.png)

```html
<mat-sidenav
    #drawer
    class="sidenav" style="height: 80%;" 
  >
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try making the sidenav be placed at the bottom right? For example youd have this:

```
.sidenav {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   height: 80%
}
```

or alternatively you can try place it to be right under the logo so for example if the logo is 100px tall you can do

```
.sidenav {
   position: absolute;
   top: 100px;
   left: 0;
}
```